# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound Won't Play Sound

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have the following code to play some brief audio, and while it plays on the iOS Simulator, it won't play on a real device.

```
NSString *fileName = @"some_file_name";

SystemSoundID alertSound;
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileName
                                         withExtension:@"wav"];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, &alertSound);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(alertSound);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, someone else in my code base was setting

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord]`.

This was causing my audio to be muted. I fixed this by changing `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with you. But the main cause is I set the category is not record type.
So my solution is set category `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];` before recording sound.

I think set category is `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` before recording sound may cause some weird problem.